# Strong Wolfe algorithm

Tags: matlab

I am working on a line search algorithm in Matlab using the Strong Wolfe conditions. My code for the Strong Wolfe is as follows:

```
while i<= iterationLimit
    if (func(x + alpha1*p)) > func(x) + c1*alpha1*(grad(x)'*p) || 
       ((func(x + alpha1*p)) >= (func(x + prevAlpha*p)) && i>1) 
            alphastar  = alpha_strongWolfe_zoom(func, grad, x, p, prevAlpha,alpha1, c1, c2);   
                break; 
    end

    if abs(((grad(x + alpha1*p))'*p)) <= -c2*(grad(x)'*p)
           alphastar  = alpha1;
                break;
    end

    if ((grad(x + alpha1*p))'*p) >= 0
        alphastar  = alpha_strongWolfe_zoom(func, grad, x, p, alpha1, prevAlpha, c1, c2); 
                break;
    end

  prevAlpha  = alpha1;
  alpha1     = gamma*alpha1; 
  i          = i+1;

  end
```

However, I am thinking that my code may not be really efficient. I was thinking that it may be a problem that I am using the full equation as given by

```
func(x + alpha1*p)
```

but I am not sure, since I cannot think of another way to do this.
Can you point out any other inefficiencies using this code? I am still a beginner when it comes to Matlab.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: [Here](https://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/accelerating-matlab-algorithms-and-applications.html) is an article describing possible ways to make MATLAB code more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit to improve the performance:

```
while (i <= iterationLimit)
    func_1 = func(x + alpha1*p);
    gp = grad(x)' * p;

    if ((func_1 > (func(x) + c1*alpha1*gp)) || ((func_1 >= func(x + prevAlpha*p)) && (i > 1)))
        alphastar = alpha_strongWolfe_zoom(func, grad, x, p, prevAlpha, alpha1, c1, c2);   
        break; 
    end

    grad_1 = grad(x + alpha1*p)' * p;

    if (abs(grad_1) <= -c2*gp)
        alphastar = alpha1;
        break;
    end

    if (grad_1 >= 0)
        alphastar = alpha_strongWolfe_zoom(func, grad, x, p, alpha1, prevAlpha, c1, c2); 
        break;
    end

    prevAlpha = alpha1;
    alpha1    = gamma*alpha1; 
    i         = i+1;
end
```

The performance is certainly not gonna skyrocket, but caching your intermediate calculations is a good starting point for optimizing yout code.

The finest optimization can only be achieved by vectorizing your computations as much as possible, but this can only be achieved through a great knowledge of the code and algorithms/maths behind it.